# How to Consume Webservice SOAP Request and response contains header and body in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I have the WSDL file from the bank whose service we have to consume. Using Apache axis 1.4 - WSDL2JAVA, I have generated all the proxy files.

There are 4 methods I have to call. Each method's SOAP 1.1 request and response contains a Header and body in them. In the request, the header is used to set the data to login and the body contains a object params to actually passe the parameters for my method `getCat`.  In the response, I have the `header_out`  which passes me the connection Status, ErrorCode (for authentication) and body contains something like

```
 <GetCatResponse xmlns="WebServices">
  <GetCatResult>
    <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</GetCatResult>
</GetCatResponse>
```

Can any one tell me how I can write the client code to send the request and get the response.

Soap looks like below.

```
 SOAPAction: "WebServices/GetCat"
  <soap:Envelope ....>
   <soap:Header>
    <ws_Header xmlns="WebServices">
     <sWebUser>string</sWebUser>
      <sWebPassword>string</sWebPassword>
      <sCompanyID>string</sCompanyID>
     </ws_Header>
    </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
     <GetCat xmlns="WebServices">
      <ObjParms>
       <sCountry>string</sCountry>
       <sCatType>string</sCatType>
       </ObjParms>
     </GetCat>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE

```
<soap:Envelope ...>
<soap:Header>
  <ws_Header_Out xmlns="WebServices">
   <sFlagStatus>int</sFlagStatus>
   <sErrorCode>string</sErrorCode>
  </ws_Header_Out>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <GetCatResponse xmlns="WebServices">
    <GetCatResult>
     <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</GetCatResult>
   </GetCatResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Axis 1.x is absolutely dreadful - I strongly urge you to use something more modern.

Comment: @skaffman We weren't able to convert WSDL2JAVA with Axis 2. No idea why.

Comment: I suggest investigating that, then, you'll likely find it more rewarding than getting anything useful out of Axis 1.

Comment: @skaffman: I will do that but I have to mention, my team has already established a common client application to handle all webservices call. Some of them have successfully established a connection with some the services with axis1.4 and we have standardised it for the application. So unless I have a good enough reason that my above prob can't be solved with axis 1.4, I can't ask all of them to change their version now.

Comment: Can anyone give me a sample client implementation of such a SOAP envelope req and resp. 1. How to set the header and body of the request and how to get the response with the header and body 2. How to get handle the data set (any)<xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</GetCatResult>

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse to generate webservice client code. You give it a WSDL (or the location of it) and it will generate all the proxies for you. See [this tutorial](http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks but I got the stub. I need to know how to get the header and body response from the stub. Any one has a tutorial that talks about this case

Comment: if I'm not mistaken you can get them from this class http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPConstants.html